# fill dataset with data from SQLDataSource asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, datasource

I've created a SQL data source which gets data from a Interbase database, I now need to manipulate some of the data I was wondering if any one knew how I can get the data from the data source into a dataset.

Any ideas or even another ways would be great.

**UPDATE**

so far I have managed to open a connection to the database using the following

```
    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```

the query I want to get the data for is

```
SELECT NAME, SORG_GP, EXPEND, INV_GP, SRTN_GP FROM MTD_FIGURE_VIEW1
```

Comment: What code have you already got? What manipulation are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this working?

```
OdbcCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NAME, SORG_GP, EXPEND, INV_GP, SRTN_GP FROM MTD_FIGURE_VIEW1";
new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
```